# How can I split a value into multiple columns in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I write a SQL query to do below function.  I have a column values with underscore `"_"`.  I want to split these values by underscore `"_"` to create two new columns named pID, nID and keep original ID column intact.

```
  Input example          Output example
   ID       |          |  pID | nID    |
1234_591856 |  ==>     | 1234 | 591856 |
12547_15795 |          | 12547| 15795  |
12_185666   |          | 12   | 18566  |
```

Comment: what it has to do with `jQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add two new columns to your table you could use ALTER TABLE:

```
alter table mytable
add column pid varchar(100),
add column nid varchar(100);
```

then you can update the value of the newly created columns:

```
update mytable
set
  pid=substring_index(id, '_', 1),
  nid=substring_index(id, '_', -1)
where
  id like '%\_%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get by below query-

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol,'_',1), 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol,'_',-1) 
FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, 
       substr(id, 1, instr(id, '_') - 1) as pId, 
       substr(id, instr(id, '_') + 1, length(id)) as nId
from your_table
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcd1cb/3)